# As Part of JMeter WEB DRIVER(Selenium Scripts) IntegrationWith Azure Pipeline and how can I add jp@gc- chrome config sampler in Azure Pipeline

Tags: selenium-webdriver, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, azure-devops, cicd

As Part of JMeter WEB DRIVER(Selenium Scripts) Integration With Azure Pipeline.I have pushed the scripts into Azure GIT Repository  and how can I add **jp@gc- chrome config sampler in Azure Pipeline?** Normally we add **jp@gc - Chrome Driver Config** in follwing way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44428349/jmeter-jpgc-webdriver-sampler but when it comes to adding in Azure Pipeline? Could anyone please help me [image]

Answer (score 0):

[Chrome Driver Config](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ChromeDriverConfig/) is a part of [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/)

You do have it already, however it looks like you made a typo, it should be `jpgc-webdriver` and you have a whitespace there

[image]

[image]

Also make sure that your test is suitable for [headless execution](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/headless-browser-selenium-python) as there will not be GUI on the Azure runner